# How to make conditional running sums in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I need to make a cumulative sum conditioned to two columns in Pandas.

Say I want to sum worker's sales in different quarters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Worker': [A, A, B, B, C, C, D, D], 'Quarter': ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 1', 'Test 2'], 'Grade': [10,8,7,6,8,10,5,7]})
df

     Worker Quarter   Sales
  0       A      Q1      10
  1       A      Q2       8
  2       B      Q1       7
  3       B      Q2       6
  4       C      Q1       8
  5       C      Q2      10
  6       D      Q1       5
  7       D      Q2       7
```

Giving me a result like this:

```
     Worker Quarter   Sales
  0       A      Q1      10
  1       A      Q2      18
  2       B      Q1       7
  3       B      Q2      13
  4       C      Q1       8
  5       C      Q2      18
  6       D      Q1       5
  7       D      Q2      12
```

What's the fastest way to do it? I'm trying nested for loops but they are pretty ugly and over a far longer database I'm concerned about losing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `groupby` with `cumsum`

```
df['Sales'] = df.groupby('Worker')['Sales'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine cumsum with transform:

```
df['Sales'] = df.groupby('Worker')['Sales'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

Output:

```
   Worker Quarter   Sales
  0       A      Q1      10
  1       A      Q2       8
  2       B      Q1       7
  3       B      Q2       6
  4       C      Q1       8
  5       C      Q2      10
  6       D      Q1       5
  7       D      Q2       7
```